# Conditional distribution of $X_1$ given $X_1 + X_2$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Assume that we have data $x =(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ and we have
 $y = (x_1+x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$
where

$Y \sim \operatorname{Multinomial}(\sum x_i,(0.5,\frac{\pi}4,\frac{1-\pi}4,\frac{1-\pi}4,\frac{\pi}4))$

I would like to know the distribution for $ X_1|X_1 + X_2$ so i try:

$$P(X_1 =x_1 | X_2  = c-x_1) =\dfrac{P(X_1 =x_1 , X_2  = c-x_1)}{P(X_2= c-x_1)} $$

But how can I get the distribution of $P(X_1 =k , X_2  = c-x_1)$? Or is there something wrong with my approach?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag as this looks like an exercise. You need to tell us more as to why you are stuck at calculating $P(X_1=x_1,X_1+X_2=y_1)$ and $P(X_1+X_2=y_1)$

Comment: How can something have a probability $\frac{1-\pi}{4}?$

Comment: @Bridgeburners, $\pi$ might be a parameter between zero and one.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Ah, my mistake. I often forget that in ML that symbol is used in contexts outside its common use in math.

Comment: I wonder how we can expect the original poster to edit this question by himself? To me it seems clear now that he/she is stuck due to taking the wrong direction (and lacks information to improve the question). The link to the meta page does not provide much information for a new, or less active, site-member on how to improve a post, especially whether there are certain 'rules', and the link is more like a discussion how longtime users of this website believe that certain questions should be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X_1 =a \vert X_1+X2=c)$ is not the same as $P(X_1=a \vert X_2=c-a)$.

Namely $$\begin{array}\\
P(X_1=a \vert X_2=c-a)&=\frac{P(X_1=a,X_2=c-a)}{P(X_2=c-a)}\\
P(X_1=a \vert X_1+X_2=c)&=\frac{P(X_1=a,X_2=c-a)}{P(X_1+X_2=c)}\end{array}$$

---

Hint how to do it instead: Let $n=X_1+X_2$. Then try to express $P(X_1|n)$ as a binomial distribution $\mathcal{B}(n,p)$.

I leave it as an exercise to figure out the $p$ in your binomial distribution based on the $p_{X_1}$ and $p_{X_2}$ from the multinomial distribution.